# ASP.Net MVC and Windows 7 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

O.K.  Stupid question.....

I sepnt nearly a day getting an MVC site working, and then I published it.

After that, the hell began.

I'm using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008 and MVC.

I published it and first the Default.aspx wouldn't come up.  I gave up on playing with that for a few and just did the easy thing a typed in default.aspx.  I'll fix that problem later.  So, I clicked on one of my navigation buttons which prior to this worked just fine in the internal development IIS, and I get a 404 error.  I spent two days surfing the Microsoft support forums and every other support forum I can find.

No fix.

So, I tried something a little different.  Just to see if I screwed up.  I created a new TestMVC application.  Set the output to a website on the local IIS.  Compiled and after typing in the default.aspx (it was set as the startup file in the project) I then clicked on the About button on the base MVC application.  And what do I get?  404.

I know this is new, folks, but this is crazy.  What is it about this process that would take this much effort to get it right, especially since it works on the test server.

Comment: Are you using Anonymous Access?

Answer (score 1):

The application pool is configured to use .net4 and integrated pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered almost the exact same issue and after hours of searching for a solution I ended up running the .NET 4.0 installers repair tool.  Miraculously this fixed the problem.